# Cache for Cordova Plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, continuous-integration, cordova-plugins

Situation: There's a Cordova project which is being built on a continuous integration system. The plugins are defined within package.json, and they're being cloned from Github/Bitbucket/wherever everytime a new build is being created.

Problem: The clone process and therefore the build itself takes lots of time as some plugins are huge.

Question: Is there a way I can cache those Cordova plugins in a central place? In my view it should only clone it once, and then incrementally pull changes. Something similar to Maven's .m2 repository.

Thanks!